# Missing routeId in direct-vm routes

Tags: apache-camel

We have found that when we have 2 routes connected via direct-vm in a transaction, with MDC logging enabled, at the point when the second route returns to the first route after the direct-vm call, the routeId in the MDC is missing (everything else in the MDC is intact).

We are on version 2.24.3 and the routes are defined in JAVA DSL bootstrapped within a springboot application.

Debugging with Camel source code takes us to
this class
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.24.3/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/MDCUnitOfWork.java
and we can see that on line 112, that is where the routeId is removed

```
// not running in route, so clear (should ideally not happen)
MDC.remove(MDC_ROUTE_ID);
```

But I don't fully understand how route context fits into the picture, how a route context is being created in the first place.
There isn't much documentation I can find about route context except that it can be used as a way to group routes in separate XML files and imported into a camel context, which is irrelevant in our case.

Anyone can shed some lights would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the UOW on the direct-vm call is done, the [CamelInternalProcessor](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.24.x/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/CamelInternalProcessor.java) .UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.after(Exchange exchange, UnitOfWork uow) is called;

On line
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.24.x/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/CamelInternalProcessor.java#L685

the routeContextStack in the UOW object is cleared at
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.24.x/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultUnitOfWork.java#L179

then on line
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.24.x/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/CamelInternalProcessor.java#L690
it's trying to get the route context object again from the stack
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.24.x/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/MDCUnitOfWork.java#L106
which would be always null as the stack has been cleared;

hence the routeId is removed from MDC as
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.24.x/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/MDCUnitOfWork.java#L112

We are on Camel 2.24.3 but the latest Camel master branch at this point seems to behave the same.